# How to organise specially formatted text to a list (on python)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, list

I've got data with flight routing codes.
It has lot's of strings like this:

```
routing = 'PBI-FLL/FMY/JAX/MIA/ORL-PNS/TPA-SRQ-CLE/CHI/HOU/WAS-DEN-ELP'
```

I need to get lists with this strings like this:

```
routinglist =  [['PBI'], ['FLL','FMY','JAX','MIA','ORL'], ['PNS','TPA'], ['SRQ'], ['CLE','CHI','HOU','WAS'], ['DEN']]
```

I wrote this code but it is to complicated and doesn't work as needed

```
routingrules = 'PBI-FLL/FMY/JAX/MIA/ORL-PNS/TPA-SRQ-CLE/CHI/HOU/WAS-DEN-ELP' 
airports = []   
nn = 0
few = ''
airportcount = 0

for simvol in routingrules:
    if (nn) % 4 == 0:
        previous = routingrules[nn:nn+3]
        if routingrules[nn+3:nn+4] == '/':
            few = few + previous + "1,2"

        elif routingrules[nn+3:nn+4] == '-':
            if few != '':
                airports.append([few + previous])
                airportcount = airportcount+1
                few = ''                
            else:
                airports.append([previous])
                airportcount = airportcount+1
        else:
            if few != '':
                airports.append([few + previous])
                airportcount = airportcount+1
                few = ''    

        nn = nn+1
    nn = nn+1 

print airports
```

it prints

```
[['PBI'], ['FLL1,2FMY1,2JAX1,2MIA1,2ORL'], ['PNS1,2TPA'], ['SRQ'], ['CLE1,2CHI1,2HOU1,2WAS'], ['DEN']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split on `-`, then each group on `/`:

```
[r.split('/') for r in routing.split('-')]
```

This outputs:

```
>>> routing = 'PBI-FLL/FMY/JAX/MIA/ORL-PNS/TPA-SRQ-CLE/CHI/HOU/WAS-DEN-ELP' 
>>> [r.split('/') for r in routing.split('-')]
[['PBI'], ['FLL', 'FMY', 'JAX', 'MIA', 'ORL'], ['PNS', 'TPA'], ['SRQ'], ['CLE', 'CHI', 'HOU', 'WAS'], ['DEN'], ['ELP']]
```

That's one extra `['ELP']` entry extra at the end there, compared to your example, but I assume that was an oversight. It's easy enough to remove that again.

Comment: Thank you very much. And may be you can help - what can I do to also split another list on space characters? I mean I need something like [r3.split(' ') for r3 in r2.split('/') for r2 in r1.split('-')]

Comment: @8am: the default for `.split()` is to split on whitespace, including collapsing multiple whitespace characters into one before splitting. List comprehensions work from left-to-right, as if the for loops are nested. So `[r3.split() for r2 in r1.split('-') for r3 in r2.split('/')]` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be (is) overkill for this problem, [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) works well here.

```
routing = 'PBI-FLL/FMY/JAX/MIA/ORL-PNS/TPA-SRQ-CLE/CHI/HOU/WAS-DEN-ELP' 

from pyparsing import *
block   = Group(delimitedList(Word(alphas), '/'))
grammar = Group(delimitedList(block, '-'))

print grammar.parseString(routing)
```

Prints:

```
[[['PBI'], ['FLL', 'FMY', 'JAX', 'MIA', 'ORL'], ['PNS', 'TPA'], ['SRQ'], ['CLE', 'CHI', 'HOU', 'WAS'], ['DEN'], ['ELP']]]
```

The advantage here comes when you want to extend the grammar. Usually these problems start simple and grow in complexity as time goes on, here separating the grammar from the parsing is useful.

Comment: Ooh, I've heard pyparsing mentioned lots of times but never seen it in action. This is really nice.

Comment: @DanielRoseman To get started I'd check out the O'Reilly book, it really helps. Paul McGuire (the author) is a regular on this site and tries to answer any specific questions that are tagged with pyparsing. I use questions like these as practice for more complex grammars I might encounter in the future, good luck!